# Support for xml highlighting for responses

Tags: paw-app

Is there any information about supporting XML highlighting in responses? In version `2.1.1` the response body is showed as raw text.

Comment: That's correct, no XML highlighting yet. It's on the TODO for quite a while, but somehow I feel like XML isn't much used, and other features would help much more users. Though, I have the project of adding some generic highlighting mechanism, so XML could be one of the available languages...